# What home expenses can I claim back from working full time at home for a business in the UK?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, tax-deduction, expenses, working-at-home

Our company is considering no longer having an office and making all the staff work from home.

We all work primarily online running a website, so our work is done purely on a computer.

With working from home, each employee will obviously be using more electricity/etc by doing so.

What are the employees entitled to claim back on expenses for working full time at home for a company in the UK?

I've found alot of information for self-employed, but I haven't found anything about employed staff working from home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Source on GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/tax-relief-for-employees/working-at-home)

> You may be able to get tax back for some of the bills you have to pay because you have to work at home on a regular basis. You can only claim for things to do with your work, eg business telephone calls or the extra cost of gas and electricity for your work area. You can’t claim for things that you use for both private and business use, eg rent or broadband access. You don’t need to provide records for claims of up to £4 per week (£18 per month). For claims over £4 per week you’ll need to provide evidence of what you’ve spent.
>
> **Claims up to £2,500**
>   You must claim using a Self Assessment tax return if you already fill one in. If you don’t already fill in a Self Assessment tax return, and your allowable expenses are under £2,500 for the tax year, fill in form P87 and send it to the address on the form. If you’ve made a successful claim in a previous tax year and your expenses are less than £1,000 (or £2,500 for professional fees and subscriptions), you may be able to make your claim by phone.
>
> **Claims over £2,500**
>   You must claim using a Self Assessment tax return.

Comment: And don't forget business travel